# Is it possible to extract values from itemgroups in TFSBuild.proj during a build

Tags: tfs

I want to extract values defined in an item group collection of TFSBuild.proj file in a C# application during a build . Can someone give me an idea as to how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

"Extract" is a weird word to use here.  If you're wanting to combine C# with MSBuild, you generally do that by [creating an MSBuild Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx).  Tasks take inputs, which can be ItemGroups and they do stuff with the items in the group.